# The second type for the line integration and the complex integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Are there the differences between the second type of the line integration of the vector function $F(x,y)=(P(x,y), Q(x,y))$ on the parametrized line $\alpha (t)$, $t\in [a, b]$ and the complex integration of the function $G(x,y)=P(x,y)+iQ(x,y)$ on $\alpha (t)$ ?

Comment: Of course. Complex integrals yield complex numbers while line integrals of the second type always yield real numbers. You should check their difference from the definition.

Comment: I want to understand the meaning of complex integration in physicx or the image of it, but it really difficult for me!!!.

Comment: this I find difficult too. Clearly it can't be seen as the work done by a force moving along a path, as in the real variable case. Perhaps you could rephrase your question as "the physical meaning of complex line integrals".